# How do I deserialize a JSON array using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

```
[
   {
      "receiver_tax_id":"1002",
      "total":"6949,15",
      "receiver_company_name":"Das Company",
      "receiver_email":"info@another.com",
      "status":0
   },
   {
      "receiver_tax_id":"1001",
      "total":"39222,49",
      "receiver_company_name":"SAD company",
      "receiver_email":"info@mail.com",
      "status":1
   }
]
```

Hi, this is my Json data, but I can't deserialize it. 
I want to check only "status" value. (first object "status" 0, second object "status" 1).

Example definition:

```
public class Example 
{
    [JsonProperty("receiver_tax_id")] 
    public string receiver_tax_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("total")] 
    public string total { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("receiver_company_name")] 
    public string receiver_company_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("receiver_email")] 
    public string receiver_email { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")] 
    public int status { get; set; } 
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
var des = (Example)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString, typeof(Example)); 
Console.WriteLine(des.status[0].ToString());
```

Comment: Show us the code that tries to deserialize your JSON.

Comment: var des = (Example)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString, typeof(Example));
Console.WriteLine(des.status[0].ToString());

Comment: And how is `Example` defined?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public class Receiver 
{
   public string receiver_tax_id { get; set;}
   public string total { get; set;}
   public string receiver_company_name { get; set;}
   public int status { get; set;}
}
```

And deserialize looks like follows:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Receiver>>(responseString);
var status = result[0].status;
```

Comment: [JsonProperty("receiver_tax_id")]
public string receiver_tax_id { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("total")]
.....

I added JsonProperty for every variable

Comment: If you use `[JsonProperty("receiver_tax_id")]` you can name your property as you want. `[JsonProperty("status")]public int MyOwnStatus { get; set; }`

Comment: I wasn't know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

If you only care about checking `status` you can use the `dynamic` type of .NET (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

```
dynamic deserialized = JObject.Parse(responseString); 
int status1 = deserialized[0].status; 
int status2 = deserialized[1].status; 
//
// do whatever
```

This way you don't even need the `Example` class.

Comment: should be JArray.Parse (or JToken.Parse + checking deserialized.Type if we are not sure if there is array on input actually)

Answer (score 4):

From your code and JSON sampels it seems the problem is you're actually deserializing a `List<Example>` rather than a single `Example`.

I would do two things:

1. Make your class follow .NET naming conventions, as you already prefixed them with the proper `JsonProperty` attributes:

   ```
   public class Example 
   {
       [JsonProperty("receiver_tax_id")] 
       public string ReceiverTaxId { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("total")] 
       public string Total { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("receiver_company_name")] 
       public string ReceiverCompanyName { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("receiver_email")] 
       public string ReceiverEmail { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("status")] 
       public int Status{ get; set; } 
   }
   ```
2. Deserialize a `List<Example>` using the generic `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` overload instead of the non-generic version you're currently using:

   ```
   var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(responseString); 
   Console.WriteLine(des[0].Status);
   ```

Comment: If you are having this problem, pay attention to this answer.  I had an array of strings as field in the object I was having this error with.  That prevented me from realizing my real problem was I was getting a list of one item at the top level and the array of strings inside that object was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to deserialize an array into an Example object. Try doing it to a List instead:

```
var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString, typeof(List<Example>)) as List<Example>;
```